# Software to join mp3 and images to make a video (like uMusic)

Tags: video, music, images, mp3

I'm looking for a better application to make videos from a music file and an image, uMusic is the perfect example, I select an MP3 file plus an JPG file and just hit render and boom, the video is created and ready to upload to YouTube. The problem with uMusic is that the image is rendered in low resolution.

I already did that with Windows Movie Maker for a batch of files but it's a really slow process and I need something simpler for the rest of the files.

Comment: Is this for Windows? (I'm guessing it is).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One possible answer - if you don't mind getting your hands a little dirty is to install [ffmpeg](http://www.ffmpeg.org) for windows then you can do this sort of thing from the command line - see this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11779490/ffmpeg-how-to-add-new-audio-not-mixing-in-video) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12938581/ffmpeg-mux-video-and-audio-from-another-video-mapping-issue/12943003#12943003) then you can even set up a batch file to do it for you, e.g. If you would like to generate a pile of uploads with the same theme music you can.

Answer (score 0):

I believe that Power Point 2013 should solve this for you. In PP2013, you can create a video of your slide show. You can add "sound" to the video, either as background music or as explanation for the slides (i.e., the typical way we do slide shows).

I am sure you realize this, but in your case, each image will be a slide in the slide show.

Let us know if that solves your problem.

Answer (score 0):

Another possible option, other than my earlier suggestion of using Power Point 2013, would be to use screen casting software.

Then, you can open your images in any image viewing app. Render them full screen. And you can play music in the background or speak your text.